# Como converter DATETIME para DATE utilizando a função NOW?

Tags: mysql, sql

Podem me dar uma dica de como posso contornar o problema abaixo ?

O objetivo da Query abaixo é retornar a quantidade de vezes que recebi os status de atendimento de ABANDON,CONGESTION e MACHINE durante um dia. Ficaria assim, se hoje é dia '2021-08-04 11:11:11' quando a query fosse executada teria que retornar o resultado do dia anterior '2021-08-04', ficando dessa maneira

```
'DISCADOR_ABANDONADAS |DISCADOR_IMPRODUTIVAS_MENSAGEM_OPERADORA |DISCADOR_IMPRODUTIVAS_SECTR
         44                          564                                  2222
```

O meu problema aqui é que não estou conseguindo converter a coluna **calldate** do tipo DATETIME para DATE pegando menos um dia. Vocês podem me indicar o que fazer nesse caso ?

```
SELECT  
    @VAR23:= COUNT(CASE WHEN statusatendimento = 'ABANDON'    THEN statusatendimento END) AS 'DISCADOR_ABANDONADAS',
    @VAR24:= COUNT(CASE WHEN statusatendimento = 'CONGESTION' THEN statusatendimento END) AS 'DISCADOR_IMPRODUTIVAS_MENSAGEM_OPERADORA',
    @VAR25:= COUNT(CASE WHEN statusatendimento = 'MACHINE'    THEN statusatendimento END) AS 'DISCADOR_IMPRODUTIVAS_SECTR_ELETRONICA_FAX',
FROM chamadas
    WHERE fila IN (1000,1002,1010,1013,1016)
    AND CAST(calldate AS DATE) =NOW()-1;
```

Comment: Qual o banco está utilizando? Veja se auxilia, substitua o "+" por "-" no seu caso: [MySQL's now() +1 day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887509/mysqls-now-1-day).

Comment: Oi Jean, consegui entender o problema. O que esta acontecendo é que por algum motivo quando tento pegar registros de um mês anterior a minha variável recebe o valor 0, estou conseguindo pegar registros somente do mês atual. Foi essa a alteração que fiz no final da Query ... AND CAST(LASTCALL AS DATE) = DATE(NOW())-7 ;